# Determine filename at an LBA (FAT)

Tags: uefi, fat, computer-forensics

My goal is to translate logged block-level accesses (LBAs) to file names. I am logging at UEFI level, so programs and boot loaders mostly read from ESP (EFI System Partition) which has a structure similar to FAT.

I know that `fsutil volume querycluster` is [able to do this](https://superuser.com/a/908283) for NTFS, is there a solution for FAT?

It is important to operate with a mounted volume and not an image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Progman Check out [this related](https://superuser.com/questions/907755/determine-filename-at-an-lba-ntfs/908283#908283) question on stack exchange, this is the same question in a different context. Although, it was supported by community unlike mine

Comment: The problem I have met is the absence of a tool. If it appears that there is no such, then I just make one on my own

Comment: A simple way to do it would be to use a sequence of TSK commands: mmls, fls and istat

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to map LBAs (sectors) to filenames (inodes) is to apply TSK utilities one by one: [mmls](https://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=Mmls), [fls](https://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=Fls) and [istat](https://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=Istat).

1. `mmls` to identify ESP partition offset
2. `fls` to retrieve tuples [filename, inode] of all files in the ESP
3. `istat` to retrieve inode -> sectors mapping

I created a [script](https://github.com/fenchelfen/essential-file-set/blob/main/utils/translate.py#L65) that produces an index from inodes (filenames) to EFI partition sectors, everybody is welcome to use it as a reference.